# Alternative to Kubernetes rolling update in rest api

Tags: api, kubernetes

After a quick search of the api docs I found out that in Kubernetes there is no rest api provided for kubectl rolling-update. Is there any other alternative for perform a rolling update by calling several apis or so? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the Kubernetes [Deployment](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/user-guide/deployments.md) object is what you are looking for. It is an object in the Kubernetes REST API (as opposed to the client-side magic in `kubectl rolling-update`).

You can specify `.spec.strategy.type==RollingUpdate` as your Deployment [Strategy](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/user-guide/deployments.md#strategy) to get similar behavior to `kubectl rolling-update`

Comment: When I try to create a Deployment I this error ```error validating "dep.json": error validating data: couldn't find type: v1beta1.Deployment; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false```

Comment: Actually in kubernetes Deployment is in early stage. And to create deployment you must set api version to "extensions/v1beta1". More details here: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.1/docs/user-guide/deployments.md.

Most of such features slowly backported from Openshift Origin back to kubernetes, see my answer below about it

Comment: @CJ Cullen  But how do i trigger this 'rolling-update' ? which command in which api trigger it?

Answer (score 1):

If kubernetes is not strict requirements and you can switch to latest openshift origin (which is "kubernetes on steroids") you can use origin feature called "deployment". Openshift deployments are accessible via api similar to general kubernetes api.

- [Information about openshift origin](https://docs.openshift.org/latest/architecture/index.html).
- [Information about openshift origin deployments](https://docs.openshift.org/latest/architecture/core_concepts/deployments.html)